# Как сделать кастомный дизайн TabLayout?

Tags: android, customview, android-tablayout, android-customview

У меня есть стандартный TabLayout который хорошо работает [image: my_tablayout]

а я хочу сделать дизайн как в этой библиотеке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://github.com/long1eu/SpaceTabLayout, сама библиотека мне не подходит, у меня не получается вписать ее в свое приложение чтобы все также хорошо работало. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно такое сделать.

Comment: а что именно не получается вписать?

Comment: @Andrew я пожалуй не очень верно выразился, у меня есть вещи которые я пока не могу повторить, но я еще работаю над ними, основная проблема в том что, библиотека сильно тормозит с моей прилой, я думаю что если можно поменять дизайн стилями а не целой либой, будет работать быстрее, но не знаю как это сделать

Answer (score 0):

Старайтесь не отступать от принципов материального дизайна и его компонентов. https://material.io/components Подобные библиотеки вероятно используют устаревший подход и наверняка не оптимизированы. Разработчики должны приводить дизайн и взаимодействие с приложением к знакомому стилю.

Попробуйте новые инструменты для создания анимаций, например MotionLayout https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout

Это вас должно очаровать
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/examples